# How to convert a text field of chars to json using pl/pgsql?

Tags: json, plpgsql

Need to take a text field such as 'O T D' and convert it to a json output like:

```
"types": [
        "O",
        "T",
        "D"
    ],
```

This is a sub output of the entire query being exported to json with the json_agg() function.
This code works in t-sql:

```
JSON_QUERY('["' + replace(rtrim(ltrim(type)), ' ','","') + '"]')  as 'types',
```

i.e. What pl/pgsql function is similar to t-sql JSON_QUERY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no PL/pgSQL function for this, but you can use SQL functions:

```
SELECT jsonb_agg(x) FROM regexp_split_to_table('O T D', ' ') AS x;

    jsonb_agg    
-----------------
 ["O", "T", "D"]
(1 row)
```